# How to add a class to a div on click, and remove the class by clicking elsewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I would like to expand a div, `filters`, when `filtertoggle` is clicked. I would like to do this by adding the class `on` to `filters`. Then, when the user clicks anywhere else on the page, I would like to remove the `on` class, thereby closing `filters`.

Here is the code I have attempted:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('body').click(function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.attr('class').includes('filtertoggle')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('.filters').slideToggle(200);
    return;
  } else {
    $(this).element.className = element.className.replace(/\bon\b/g, "");
    return;
  });
```

As it stands, `filters` does not open.

Comment: Why not just use a `focus()` event handler? Or just `:focus` in CSS?

Comment: Please show us your html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have inherited the code and am rejigging a function that previously worked, which relies on adding the `on` class. The current code does not remove the `on` class unless you click `filtertoggle` again, which is restrictive.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen which html do you need to see?

Answer (score 3):

Your logic has a couple of issues. Firstly, `evt.target` is an Element object, not a jQuery object, so it has not `attr()` method. You need to wrap it in a jQuery object to make that work. Then you can use `hasClass()` to check what class is on the `target`.

Also a jQuery object has no `element` property, so `element.className` will cause a syntax error. You can just use `removeClass()` in that case. Try this:

```js
$('body').click(function(evt) {
  if ($(evt.target).hasClass('filtertoggle')) {
    $('.filtertoggle').addClass('on');
    $('.filters').slideToggle(200);
  } else {
    $('.filtertoggle').removeClass('on');
    $('.filters').slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

```css
body, html { height: 100%; }
.on { color: #C00; }
.filters { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtertoggle">
  FilterToggle
</div>

<div class="filters">
  Filters...
</div>
```

You should also note that it may be possible to achieve this in CSS alone, depending on how your HTML is structured. You can use the `:focus` selector to do it, like this:

```css
body, html { height: 100%; }
.filtertoggle { outline: 0; }
.filters { 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.filtertoggle:focus { color: #C00; }
.filtertoggle:focus + .filters { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtertoggle" tabindex="1">
  FilterToggle
</div>

<div class="filters">
  Filters...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. I forgot to mention that jquery tags are already present. I will try to incorporate your suggestions. I'll bear the html/css solution in mind for future projects, but given the nature of the pre-existing code here I'm keen to stick to jquery for now.

Comment: Just a note, the addClass and removeClass lines should target `filters` rather than `filtertoggle`. I've adjusted this in the code, and `filters` expands as it should when `filtertoggle` is clicked, however it immediately slides back and disappears, regardless of whether I click. Do you know why this may be happening?